# Changing h to (-h) in the definition of the derivative

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

I don't understand why it seems to be the case that

$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x-h)-f(x)}{h}=-f'(x)$$

It would mean that

$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x-h)-f(x)}{h}=-\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$$

I there some nice way to go about showing this is the case?

Comment: More generally, $$\lim_{h\to0} g(h)=\lim_{h\to0} g(-h)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

think about what this limit definition shows:
$$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$$
it is a small change in $f$, $df$ over a small change in $x$, $h$. How in your case:
$$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x-h)-f(x)}{h}=-\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x)-f(x-h)}{h}$$
so you can think of it as representing that same small change, but in the opposite direction, hence it being $-\frac{df}{dx}$

---

Another way to show it would be, let $H=-h$ and so:
$$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x-h)-f(x)}{h}=\lim_{H\to0}\frac{f(x+H)-f(x)}{-H}$$

[Here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/09smbyx249) is a graph to show you what the limit looks like, change $f(x)$ to whatever you want and look at what happens as $h\to0$